# xterm no absolute path found for shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal, xterm, suse

I am trying to run a script in SUSE Linux Enterprise 12 from java using `ProcessBuilder`. Codes for this follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("xterm", "-e", "script_path");
Process pr = pb.start();
```

then I read the messages from `Process`, it is saying `xterm: no absolute path found for shell: script_path`

So I tried from the **Gnome-Terminal** I have in SUSE, and used the commands `xterm script_path` but found the same error message. I tried both form root and from local user. I am completely out of clues about this error.

And the main condition is I have to able to run this code as root as my java code has to be invoked as root only.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried again and now I actually have a new error message from the `ProcessBuilder`. The message I get from the `errorstream` follows:

```
error extracting:: error message: Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user. 
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted in this environment. 
You may get a more escriptive message by running the program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable. 
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

The script I am trying to execute is `unZipper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo unzip -o postgresql-9.4.6-linux-64.zip -d some_path/db/
sleep 3
```

Comment: What does `xterm -v` say?

Comment: in ProcessBuilder or in the terminal?

Comment: In the terminal.  That would show the version of xterm.

Comment: @thomas `X.Org 7.7.0(308)`

Comment: The `$DISPLAY` variable is a different question (and has been asked [several times](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=root+display+variable)).

Answer (score 3):

xterm makes a few (different) checks for the pathnames involved in executing a command.  Here is a synposis:

- if you say "xterm -e command", xterm will rely upon your existing `$SHELL` setting and/or the configuration of `luit` (which also uses `$SHELL` in a different way) to decide if the command will succeed.
- if you say "xterm command" (no `-e` option), xterm treats that as a special case, requiring that it is an absolute pathname.  This is where the usual problem arises.

In changes from [patch #301](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_301) onward (and except for the special no `-e` case) xterm checks the existing `$SHELL` to ensure that it is listed in `/etc/shells`.  (There's a long story here, but summarize by noting that it's an improvement in security..).  If you read the changelog, you can see that getting it right took a few tries to handle special cases.

From the information given:

- Since you're using `-e` in one case (from ProcessBuilder) and not in the other, there may be some problem there.
- Or your `$SHELL` may not be listed in `/etc/shells`.
- Finally, there could be some resource setting (combined with incorrect locale variables) causing the program to execute `luit` unexpectedly.  For instance, if xterm tries to use `luit` but the `localeFilter` resource is set to a relative path, that would give this error.

Comment: my `$SHELL` is /bin/bash and it is in `/etc/shells` included. btw, I have updated my ques as I have a new error message.

Comment: The usual practice is to start a new question if the information is not a clarification of the original question.